# What are some permanent shower shelf options?

Tags: shower

I have found shower caddies and suction cup add-ons, but I want to add shelves to my shower surround that are permanent.  I haven't had much lucking finding anything.  What are my options, and where do I get them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buy/find/scrape up a small piece of corian. I'll bet you might find something online, or even better, go to a countertop maker in your area. They will surely have some scraps that you can take off their hands for a small fee. A square foot piece is scrap to them, so they might as well make a few dollars extra from it.

Cut into a triangular shape, to fit into a corner of the shower. You might also choose a quarter quadrant of a circle as the shape. The nice thing about corian is it works well with saws, routers, hand saws, files, etc. And you can sand the edges smooth, even to a glossy finish. Make a pair of blocks from the same corian, 1 inch high, and as long as the edges of your triangular shape. These will be supports for the shelf.

Now, glue the supports to the wall of the stall, using a high quality silicon as an adhesive. Angle the shelf just slightly down, so that any water on it will drain properly, but not enough so that something placed on it will freely slide off. Glue down the shelf with the same silicon to the supports and to the wall.

Comment: Not as friendly on the tools, but I've also seen triangles of 12x12 or larger tile used -- they trimmed a little off the bottom of the two tiles going in on the wall there, and just slotted the triangle in the gap.  (I'm not sure if all tiles would be rated for this ... I want to say it was a cut stone, like marble, but it was a hotel bathroom, and I can't even remember where or when I saw it)

Comment: I'm sure that marble would work nicely here. The only problem with this general idea (corian, marble, etc.) is if the enclosure walls are too flexible. Flexing behind the glued on shelf will cause the glue to peel away before long.

Comment: You could also cut the point out, and angle the shelf downwards in that direction for drainage. (i.e. towards the corner)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a couple of places that sell items that look promising.

http://www.universalplastics.com/store
http://www.caddycoinc.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess this depends on the material in your shower surround.  If it is anything "hard" - tiles, hard panels, whatever... then I would go with [corner shelving](http://www.tileshop.com/product/productdetail.aspx?familyID=910&recordID=382248&gclid=COLry9qxjLcCFcIv4AodlnsAmA).  If you have tile they usually recommend installing with construction adhesive and then caulking.  If you have panels sometimes it is construction adhesive and sometimes it is epoxy.  These are very easy to put up (however if you need to buy the epoxy it is sometimes hard to find).